# Image viewer is looping first image in array when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I've been trying to fix this for a long time and it's really annoying me as its a simple issue I just can't figure it out, I am trying to make a next-previous style image viewer but when I press the next button a couple of times and view all images it takes two clicks to cycle to the next image, any help would be great, The code may not be in the greatest format or be very efficient so any advice on that would be appreciated greatly, thank you.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./mainImage.css">
    <title>Image Gallery</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="main">
      <img id='image1' src="">
      <button onclick="next()">next</button>
      <!--<button onclick="prev()">prev</button>-->
      <p id='check'>gf</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

- Javascript:

```
var images = [
        "cow.PNG",
        "del.PNG",
        "falafel.PNG"
      ]

var count = 0;
var dis = document.getElementById('image1')

function loadImg(imgIndex){
  dis.src=images[imgIndex];
}

function next(){
   if(count >= 0 && count < images.length){
      loadImg(count);
      count++;
    } else {
      count=0;
      loadImg(count);
    }
   }

window.onload = next()
```

Comment: Here's a shorter way: https://jsfiddle.net/madnkb49/

Comment: The reason for the issue is the inconsistency between if and else; you're either 1. displaying image[count], then 2. advancing count or 1. advancing count, then 2. displaying image[count]. This causes image 0 to get displayed twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because of different order in branches of condition operator in your `next()` function. When your counter is more than length of array you first set counter to 0 and then load an image, but on the next click you first load the image with 0 index and only then increment the counter, probably better to simplify your function e.g. like this:

```
function next() {
  count++;
  if (count == images.length) count = 0;
  loadImg(count);
}
```

and call `loadImg()` function when page has been loaded:

```
window.onload = loadImg(count);
```